# controller breaks the directive when in the same module

Tags: angularjs

This is what I have in my js file:

```
//classRelationship.directive.js
'use strict';

angular.module('app.class',[]).directive('classRelationship', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'I AM HERE'
    };
});

angular.module('app.class',[]).controller('classRelationshipCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.info('test');
}]);
```

And this is my html:

```
// main.html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Manage Students</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <class-relationship></class-relationship> 
    </div>

</div>
```

At this point the `I AM HERE` is not coming up in the html page, when I remove the controller or change the module the directive gets claled and i can see the template text in the html, i.e.

```
//classRelationship.directive.js
'use strict';

angular.module('app.class',[]).directive('classRelationship', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'I AM HERE'
    };
});

angular.module('app.aNewModule',[]).controller('classRelationshipCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.info('test');
}]);
```

I am not getting any errors on the js console or any warnings and there's nothing else attached to that module `app.class`. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling

```
angular.module('app.class',[])
```

twice.

That **defines** the module, and thus overwrites the previously defined module.

To **get a reference** to a previously defined module, you need to use the function without the second array parameter:

```
angular.module('app.class').controller(...
```